# group ranges of consecutive numbers

Tags: sqlite

Consider table :

```
Point    | Seq_number|timestamp
------------------------------
50000    | 3002      |6000
-----------------------------
50001    | 3003      |7000
------------------------------
50002    | 3004      |1000
------------------------------
50003    | 3005      |2000
------------------------------
50004    | 1         |3000
------------------------------
50005    | 2         |4000
------------------------------
50006    | 3         |4000
------------------------------
50007    | 4         |4000
------------------------------
50008    | 5         |5000
------------------------------
50009    | 6         |10000
------------------------------
and so on records
------------------------------
```

I want all records in
time stamp range = 1000 to 7000
point range = 50000 to 50030 excluding 50003
sort above table in ascending order by sequence number.

I have written SQL query as

```
select *
from ( select *
       from NV_DB_LOGLKUP
       where point IS NOT 50003
         and point between 50000 and 53000 ) 
where timestamp between 1000 and 7000
order by seq_number asc ;
```

The above query is working.The result of above query will be :
[image]

For above table shared, I want to write generic SQL query which will give me output as 
[image]

The entry in output table is made when 'either or both'  of seq_num and point is not sequential to previous record in input table.
Note: 50004 to 50008 , seq_number is sequential. same for 50000 to 50002. But for 50030 record , point is not sequential to its prev record point (50002) . Also for 50031 record, seq_num is not sequential to its prev record seq_number (3005).

Im open to change SQL query written above and make it more compact.

Thank you

Comment: expecte output also ...?

Comment: I require some inputs for writing query , Half query is written, the one I have shared above. Now on output of that query , I want to have query which will give me list of records... Like List 1: List1 : 50004 to 50008 List2 : 50000 to 50002.

Comment: list means, comma seperated, or  row wise, You can edit the question with  expected output.

Comment: Thanks Subin. I have updated my output. But m also interested in knowing how comma separated output is possible. M trying to solve it by creating temporary table , but if there any other way is possible and If I can access output of query then I have no issue.

Comment: Which DB you are using??

Comment: I m using Sqlite3 database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96209/discussion-between-amruta-and-subin-c-poonamgode).

Answer (score 0):

A row is the first row in a range if there is no previous row:

```
WITH interesting_data AS (
  SELECT point,
         seq_number
  FROM NV_DB_LOGLKUP
  WHERE point BETWEEN 50000 AND 53000
    AND point != 50003
    AND timestamp BETWEEN 1000 AND 7000
)
SELECT point AS first_point
FROM interesting_data
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM interesting_data AS previous
                  WHERE previous.point = interesting_data.point - 1);
```

The corresponding last row is the first row at or behind the first point that has no next point:

```
WITH interesting_data AS (
  SELECT point,
         seq_number
  FROM NV_DB_LOGLKUP
  WHERE point BETWEEN 50000 AND 53000
    AND point != 50003
    AND timestamp BETWEEN 1000 AND 7000
), first_points AS (
  SELECT point AS first_point,
         seq_number
  FROM interesting_data
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM interesting_data AS previous
                    WHERE previous.point = interesting_data.point - 1)
)
SELECT first_point,
       (SELECT MIN(point)
        FROM interesting_data
        WHERE point >= first_points.first_point
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM interesting_data AS next
                          WHERE next.point = interesting_data.point + 1)
       ) AS last_point
FROM first_points
ORDER BY seq_number;
```

If you have an older SQLite version that does not support WITH, update it, or write the queries as views, or insert them directly as subqueries.

Comment: Thanks CL for answering. I have modified above query to suite my question: Please have look